# flex cheatsheet for lifecyle methods and overrideable UIComponent functions

Tags: documentation, flex3, reference

HI,

O.K, not technically a programming question but it's still relevent for this forum I think.

I'm wondering if theres any cheat sheets around for flex?

Ideally I'm really looking for some comrehensive list of lifecycle events and functions such as creationComplete, preinitilize etc.
Also It would be really cool to get a comprehensive list of overridable methods, espically for UIComponents such as resize and draw etc?

Sometime's digging through the documentation winds up unsuccessful because theres so much (I guess thats a skill in its self). It would be great if there was a list that I could just scan through to determerine if theres any functions that could help me out in times of need !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know any cheat sheet but I do recommend this presentation:
http://www.slideshare.net/hominhchuc/owenumbaugh360flex-1221867544208999-8-presentation

I used it back in the day to learn this, I think it's very efficient and effective.